# How to prevent close the DrawerLayout onTouch of screen?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I had implement `DrawerLayout` in my application. Now if suppose I click on screen then the `DrawerLayout` is getting close. But now I want to implement some operations on `onTouch`.

My question is how can I prevent the `DrawerLayout` to close `onTouch`. I want to implement this like suppose I dismiss the `onTouch` event of `DrawerLayout`.

If any suggestion please share with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in the navigation drawer sample from the developer site this  `mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList)` closes the drawer comment this line and your drawer will not close. You are closing the drawer on selection of an item in the drawer  list.

Comment: what about locking/unlocking the drawer to prevent unwanted closing?

Answer (score 0):

Its not actually a proper solution but is a workaround increase the drawer width so that it covers majority of the screen.Doing this your drawer will get most of the touch events and therefore wont close on touch.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawerContentList"
    style="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" >
</ListView>
```

increase `android:layout_width` to say around `320dp`